# Modify menu items for Mac application

Tags: cocoa

How can I add/delete default menu items on app ? By default there's About section, File, Format, View, Window & Help. How can I delete these items ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add : Drag `NSMenuItem` in your main menu.

[image]

Delete : Drag `NSMenuItem` out from main menu.
[image]

Comment: I ended up adding these `[[NSApp mainMenu] removeItem:[[NSApp mainMenu] itemWithTitle:@"Window"]]` thought there was no way to do it in Xib.